# Is there any permanent inhibition of maltase production in yeast by glucose

Tags: fermentation, yeast

Is is there any long term or "memory effect" on the expression of maltase in yeast that has been grown or mainly grown with glucose? In effect does yeast grown with glucose "forget" (or have some form of continuing metabolic impediment) how to metabolise maltose?
A somewhat technical question prompted by discussion elsewhere. Catabolic inhibition by glucose is well known and documented. Glucose is preferentially absorbed by yeast and an excess of it will repress the uptake and cleaving of maltose as a result. My understanding is that once the glucose is depleted (or drops below threshold levels) the yeast is once again free to transport maltose through the cell membrane and express maltase to catabolise it. Does anyone one know any different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeast will consume the all sugars available equally, but glucose goes first. Mainly because the smaller molecular size of the simple sugar and cell wall surface area. Because feeding and cell growth continue during fermentation, there are more and more bud scars that physically block larger sugar molecules in areas of the cell wall. The new cells created are usually short lived as they Haven't had the chance for nutrient uptake to have strong cell walls to tolerate the ABV.

As far as the actual pathways changing or a limitaion of Maltase production. I don't believe this to be the case, it's just an issue of cell wall surface capable of receiving the large molecule. The maltase never gets to contact the maltose if the maltose is hindered into the pathway.

A culture grown on just glucose can be grown into new cells that can accept maltose, by keeping the step starters low in OG, mostly made up of complex sugars and retarding the metabolism with cool temps.